# How to associate two equal child elements?

Tags: java, selenium

I need to locate the following element:

```
String myString = driver.getElement(By.xpath("//tr//input[name='ID1']//td[3]//b")).getText();
```

However this is not working because `<input and <td` elements are equal childs of `<tr`. I must use `<input` to find this element. How can I do this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID1" value="87660">

<td class="mainCtr" valign="top">

    <input type="checkbox" id="trans2660" onclick="doIndividual(this);"> 

    <a href="javascript: .............
    </a>

</td>

<td class="mainCtr" valign="top">

</td>

<td class="mainLt" valign="top">
  <b>Grovl</b><br>
  3<br>
 </td>
<td class="maowsLt" valign="top">
  7052<br>
  L323<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it a couple ways

**1.** You can use "follow-sibling".

I havent used this property enough to post code for it but you can look it up here https://www.google.com/search?q=xpath+following-sibling&oq=follow+siblin&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.3639j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

**2.** Get the parent of the input and find the 3rd td

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr//input[name='ID1']"));
WebElement parent = inputElement.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
String myBoldText = parent.findElement(By.xpath("//td[3]//b")).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `..` to go up one level.

Supposing we had HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="sibling">Stuff</li>
    <li class="target">Target</li>
</ul>
```

We can find the list element with class "target" through its sibling with class "sibling", like so:

```
//ul/li[@class="sibling"]/../li[@class="target"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if cssSelctors are used,

```
String myString = driver.getElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='ID1'] td.mainLt>b")).getText();
```

The UI changes more often, so for automated test cases i suggest you to choose cssSelector over xpath..

[click here for more info about cssSeletors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS)